# Option tag not appearing in select Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript array and I want to iterate through it to create the options in a `<select>` tag.

```
var sBoxContent = "categorieBox_content";
var oBoxContent = document.getElementById(sBoxContent);

oBoxContent.innerHTML += "<select name=\"clientCategories\">";

for(var i=0;i<oClientCategories.length;i++) {
        var categorieId = oClientCategories[i].id;
        var categorieLabel = oClientCategories[i].label;

        oBoxContent.innerHTML += "<option value=\"" + categorieId + "\">" + categorieLabel + "</option>";
 }

oBoxContent.innerHTML += "</select>";
```

The array is working properly since the option is displayed correctly but it appears outside the `<select>` tag.

HTML:

```
<td>
<select name="clientCategories"></select>
<option value="1">CategoryName</option>
</td>
```

Comment: Because innerHTML is not like building a string. It closes the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `innerHTML` attempts to always create valid syntax,

```
oBoxContent.innerHTML += "<select name=\"clientCategories\">";
```

actually creates this DOM snippet:

```
<select name="clientCategories"></select>
```

Therefore you need to assemble your HTML string first, before you assign it to `innerHTML`:

```
var sBoxContent = "categorieBox_content";
var oBoxContent = document.getElementById(sBoxContent);
var myHTML = "";


myHTML += "<select name=\"clientCategories\">";

for(var i=0;i<oClientCategories.length;i++) {
        var categorieId = oClientCategories[i].id;
        var categorieLabel = oClientCategories[i].label;

        myHTML += "<option value=\"" + categorieId + "\">" + categorieLabel + "</option>";
 }

myHTML += "</select>";
oBoxContent.innerHTML += myHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` is weird and doesn't quite work like a string.  The HTML you pass in is parsed, so the initial `<select>` you are passing in gets closed automatically.

Instead, build it as one string and use `innerHTML` after the fact.

```
var oBoxContentHTML = "<select name='clientCategories'>";
// etc.
oBoxContent.innerHTML += oBoxContentHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use document.createElement() instead of just messing with the HTML strings.

```
var oClientCategories = [{id: 1, label:"one"},{id: 2, label: "two"},{id: 3, label: "three"}];
var selectBox = document.createElement("select");

for(var i=0;i<oClientCategories.length;i++){
    var elem = oClientCategories[i];
    var addedOption = document.createElement("option");
    addedOption.value = elem.id;
    addedOption.innerHTML = elem.label;
    selectBox.appendChild(addedOption);
}

var cont = document.getElementById("categorieBox_content");
cont.appendChild(selectBox);
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V3fjx/